# Checking for a specific string inside an attribute

Tags: ndepend

I want to display all the methods that have the Obsolete tag. This one I can do.
However we use a string to define in which release the method was obsoleted.

```
[Obsolete("2013.1")]
```

is it possible to access that string using the CQL?